# Performance Measures

Tags: performance, weka, measure, precision-recall, performance-measuring

I have to do combine Classification Accuracy (A), Precision (P) and Recall (R) on the minority class measures into one measure M by: M=w1*A+w2*P+W3*R where w1, w2 and w3 are weighting factors for A, R and P respectively.

I am not sure what are the weighting factors here for this linear model formula?

Thank you very much for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

That sound like you have to come up with those weights yourself depending on your specific needs. Alternatively, I'd suggest using the well known F1 score, which Weka already provides: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score